nativescript, module flutter: page app Android assets Unable to load asset:"AssetManifest.bin" The asset does not exist or has empty data
I'm implementing a flutter module in a nativescript project. Basically a widget on a page that displays an asset that is normally stored in App_Resources/Android/src/res/drawable-* in Android... in Flutter according to the documentation they are stored in assets/*. The problem is that when implementing it in nativescript a box of red lines appears on the screen and the message "Cannot load asset: "AssetManifest.bin" The asset does not exist or has empty data."
Does anyone know if there is any special configuration so that the assets can be displayed?
pubspec.yaml
assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/icons/woman.png

Widget
 Image.asset(
                          'assets/icons/woman.png', // Ruta del asset
                          width: 200, // Tamaño del ícono
                          height: 200,
                        ),

Place the assets directory in different places in the nativescript project. Even in the App_Resources all the files are located according to the size of the drawable-**
